# compute suffix maximums using itertools.accumulate

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, python-itertools

What's the recommended way to compute the suffix maximums of a sequence of integers?

Following is the brute-force approach (`O(n**2)`time), based on the problem definition:

```
>>> A
[9, 9, 4, 3, 6]
>>> [max(A[i:]) for i in range(len(A))]
[9, 9, 6, 6, 6]
```

One `O(n)` approach using `itertools.accumulate()` is the following, which uses two list constructors:

```
>>> A
[9, 9, 4, 3, 6]
>>> list(reversed(list(itertools.accumulate(reversed(A), max))))
[9, 9, 6, 6, 6]
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: I don't think this is `O(n)` if you apply `max` to increasingly more numbers.

Comment: It doesn't - it's just max of two numbers repeatedly. And some quick testing corroborates the `O(n)` estimate.

Comment: @ReutSharabani yeah, `itertools.accumulate` works like reduce in that it takes a binary operator, except instead of *reducing* to a single number, it accumulates all intermediate results. Anyway, I think your `itertools.accumualte` solution is pretty pythonic. But even an equivalent for-loop would be fine.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slice-reversal makes things more concise and less nested:

```
list(itertools.accumulate(A[::-1], max))[::-1]
```

It's still something you'd want to bundle up into a function, though:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def suffix_maximums(l):
    return list(accumulate(l[::-1], max))[::-1]
```

If you're using NumPy, you'd want `numpy.maximum.accumulate`:

```
import numpy

def numpy_suffix_maximums(array):
    return numpy.maximum.accumulate(array[::-1])[::-1]
```

Comment: Definitely looks more pythonic. Correct me if I am wrong, but this creates 3 lists - one using the explicit list constructor and the rest due to the slices. No?

Comment: @SoumyaroopRoy: Yes. [The performance implications of creating extra lists probably won't behave as you expect if you're used to a language like C++, though.](https://ideone.com/Rzm31o) Python has super weak compile-time optimization, dynamic dispatch instead of templates, and dynamically allocated everything, so allocating a few extra lists isn't actually expensive relative to other operations.

Answer (score 1):

Personally when I think "Pythonic" I think "simple and easy-to-read", so here's my Pythonic version:

```
def suffix_max(a_list):
    last_max = a[-1]
    maxes = []
    for n in reversed(a):
        last_max = max(n, last_max)
        maxes.append(last_max)
    return list(reversed(maxes))
```

For what it's worth, this looks to be about 50% slower than the `itertools.accumulate` approach, but we're talking 25ms vs 17ms for a list of 100,000 ints, so it may not much matter.

If speed is the utmost concern and the range of numbers you expect to see is significantly smaller than the length of list you're working with, it might be worth using [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding):

```
def suffix_max_rle(a_list):
    last_max = a_list[-1]
    count = 1
    max_counts = []
    for n in a_list[-2::-1]:
        if n <= last_max:
            count += 1
        else:
            max_counts.append([last_max, count])
            last_max = n
            count = 1
    if n <= last_max:
        max_counts.append([last_max, count])
    return list(reversed(max_counts))
```

This is about 4 times faster than the above, and about 2.5 times faster than the itertools approach, for a list of 100,000 ints in the range 0-10000. Provided, again, that your range of numbers is significantly smaller than the length of your lists, it will take less memory, too.